# Dictionary type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In a few places in my application, I'm declaring a dictionary types, like:

```
interface MyInterface {
    data: { [key: string]: Item };
}
```

Is there in TypeScript any built-in shorthand for the dictionaries/maps, to get something similar to:

```
interface MyInterface {
    data: Dict<Item>;
}
```

Comment: You can try Record<K,T> for more details https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

We can try with built-in typescript advanced type called `Record<K, T>`. Here is official documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

```
interface MyInterface {
    data: Record<string, Item>;
}
```

Put everything together here

```
interface Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

interface MyInterface {
    data: Record<string, Item>;
}

const obj: MyInterface = {
    data: {
        "123": { id: "123", name: "something" }
    }
};
```

Comment: Since keys will be always `string`: `type Dictionary<T> = Record<string, T>`
`Record` is much better than my previous attempt, thanks.